# No template sub-directory with name 'base' found in the following paths:

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, voila

I'm trying to run a jupyter notebook using `voila` on my mac M1.
When I run `pip3 install voila`, the installation succeeds, however, when running `voila` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/voila", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/app.py", line 370, in initialize
    self.setup_template_dirs()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/app.py", line 376, in setup_template_dirs
    self.template_paths = collect_template_paths(['voila', 'nbconvert'], template_name, prune=True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/paths.py", line 24, in collect_template_paths
    return collect_paths(app_names, template_name, include_root_paths=True, prune=prune, root_dirs=root_dirs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voila/paths.py", line 90, in collect_paths
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'base' found in the following paths:
```

I've been trying to work around this by specifying templates from other folders, but currently nothing works.

`which voila` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/voila`

`which python3` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates seem to be installed under `/opt/homebrew/share/jupyter`.

`voila` can't find the template dirs in any of the Jupyter location:

```
jupyter --paths
```

One way to fix it is to link to the template dirs to one of the locations voila is looking at (I chose `~/Library/Jupyter` based on the output of the above command):

First make sure the folders exist:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Jupyter/voila
mkdir -p ~/Library/Jupyter/nbconvert
```

Then link the template dirs:

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/voila/templates ~/Library/Jupyter/voila/templates
ln -s /opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates ~/Library/Jupyter/nbconvert/templates
```